# Как изменить шрифты в Android?

Tags: android

У меня есть 2 шрифта. Lacosta и Dagos

Также есть готовое приложение. Мне нужно в этом приложении во всех Activity(всего 10), заменить на шрифт Dagos.

Как это сделать быстро? чтобы не менять для каждого View шрифт. ибо это геморой полнейший

Короче я решил создать класс

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {
public MyTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    Typeface typeface= Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "pfagorasanspro-medium.ttf");
    this.setTypeface(typeface);
}
```

}

И заменил все на MyTextView.

Теперь получаю ошибку. Что делать?

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to com.eranewgames.donatello.MyView.MyTextView
                                                                         at com.eranewgames.donatello.Auth.onCreate(Auth.java:33)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16883281/3212712

Comment: А в чем простите геморой? Разве поиск и замера по всему проекту (Ctrl+Shift+R) не позволит с этим справится за пару минут?

Comment: попробуйю отпишусь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно наследовать TextView и применить программно к нему шрифт, и во всем приложении использовать уже свой кастомный TextView

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TextViewPlus extends TextView {
    private static final String TAG = "TextView";

    public TextViewPlus(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TextViewPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    public TextViewPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    private void setCustomFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextViewPlus);
        String customFont = a.getString(R.styleable.TextViewPlus_customFont);
        setCustomFont(ctx, customFont);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) {
        Typeface tf = null;
        try {
        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), asset);  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface: "+e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }

        setTypeface(tf);  
        return true;
    }

}
```

**attrs.xml: (в res/values)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="TextViewPlus">
        <attr name="customFont" format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**Положите "Dagos.ttf" в папку assets**

```
<com.example.TextViewPlus
        android:id="@+id/textViewPlus1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/showingOffTheNewTypeface"
        foo:customFont="saxmono.ttf">
    </com.example.TextViewPlus>
```

Comment: Можно если программу пишешь с нуля. А у меня этих TextView штук 500.

А через глобальный поиск опасно делать ибо может много чего затереть

Answer (score -1):

Можно написать рекурсивную функцию которая на вход будет принимать корневой layout и устанавливать шрифт, соответственно с проверками